# Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Permission denied)

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, email, vps

Email Sending failed from VPS. It works fine from my localhost but not working in live server. my code is given below.

```
   $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'my gmail email',
        'smtp_pass' => 'email password',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('from-email', 'name');
    $this->email->to('to-email');
    $this->email->subject('Hello Test');
    $this->email->message('Hello Message');
    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'send';
    }else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

It works fine in **localhost**.
In my **VPS** server, it shows error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Permission denied)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1990

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/company/application/controllers/Welcome.php
Line: 46
Function: send

File: /var/www/html/company/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

[image: Error screenshot from browser]

I also changed my **smtp_port** from **465** to **587** and **25**. It remains the same error.

How do I solve this?

***Can anyone tell me, how do I check 465 port is open or not in the server?***
My VPS server os is: **centos**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I try this, it's work for me. 
I hope it's work for you too

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';    
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you check on the ports, make sure your server firewall is *permitting smtp*. 
You might have to check on

- port 25

.

Comment: Please provide some explanation how this can answer to the question

Comment: If the smpt port is not working, the smtp send mail will fail. So make sure your firewall permits traffic on the port 25, or whichever the port you using for smtp.